# VSE: how to change mask position per frame

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I'm used to using the red record button at the bottom, which allows the mask to move with the object in question.

I have an animation that isn't fluid enough to allow this though, and the frames skip alot, so using that method just captures dead space in between.

I want to make a mask and edit it frame by frame. SO say I want to capture a square that is in the top right of my screen in frame 1, and in frame 3 it just jumps all the way to the right bottom of the screen, then its top right....top left..etc. all over the place each frame. SO if i do the red button way, I got it moving and capturing blank space in between the frames.
If I set it frame by frame the mask doesn't move, it just resets to the original position when i change the frame...idk how to make it stay in the new spot on the frame I modify it on.